# GWT Chart library - ability to blow-up components inside the chart

Tags: gwt, charts

I have a specific requirement for my GWT charting library. I need a library that supports a variety of graphs (bar, line, pie) and should have the ability to handle events from inside a chart (like clicking on a bar inside the bar graph - this would allow me to show extra information as a popup when its clicked).

I know that conventional wisdom states that its not possible without using Flash/Flex or a third-party embedded component but I am assuming that there would be a HTML5 charting library that would allow me to do it. I have tried to search but unsuccessfully. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have not mentioned whether you wish to have commercial or open source options. Also you should list out options you explored. Strangely stackoverflow displays ads for FusionChart along side your question and that site already has comparison with other poular libs!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of FusionCharts. They have fancy charts but missed the market trend towards HTML5 and allowed Highchart to pick up charting market.

A good way to analyze is to pick up Fusion Charts competition as starting point and then list out your parameters.The below link is heavy duty marketing. Use it only to know what Fusion Chart' competitors are.
http://www.fusioncharts.com/success-stories/competition-and-us/

The rest of the content on the above link is more of marketing bs.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Charts](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) support all that, AFAIK.

Or is that answer too obvious ?

And there is a GWT wrapper available.